# How to make module package name the same with project package in androidstudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to make the module package name, the same with project package in `androidstudio`?

I have to make the module package name the same with my app's package name,because I use reflection in my code.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the Gradle modules?

Comment: yes.project refer the module

Comment: I had try 
 enforceUniquePackageName = false
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
in the project build.gradle

Comment: Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/meizu/gameservice/BuildConfig;
error show in my terminal.